# Firebase hosting root is setup but subdomain also showing firebase 404 even though only root is pointed

Tags: heroku, firebase-hosting

I want to hook the root of my goDaddy domain to firebase. `omarhabash.com`. When i go there, I see it correctly but for some reason www.omarhabash.com shows a firebase 404. I don't want that cause www should be pointed to heroku.

The heroku site is hooked via cname but does not show it - instead i see firebase which should only be set via a record `@`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to add to the `www` subdomain the A records with the same Firebase IP addresses, and then add the new subdomain in the Firebase Hosting dashboard. If you already verified the main domain, this should be ready more quickly.